# Merchant authentication using JSON request - Authorize.Net

Tags: java, php, ruby-on-rails, json, authorize.net

This Doc [Click here](https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/#payment-transactions) clearly tells me about the merchant authentication. However they only provide the content type : text/xml. Api end point for it is https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api ( sandbox account ).

How can I send a JSON request with name and transaction key as the keys? Also, what is the End Point to which I should send this request for mechant authentication?

Official DOC doesn't help. :'( Was hoping you could. DHC or HttpClientRequester doesn't help too. Getting error.

Comment: I don't believe the API offers json yet

Comment: @JohnConde Umm.. Yeah. I think you are right. :-/ Why don't they?

Comment: It's coming relatively soon. :)

Comment: JSON is now in Beta for Authorize.Net: http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/JSON-Beta-New-Product-Ideas-Forum/ba-p/48721

Answer (score 0):

Authorize.net now works with JSON. 
Following is a valid JSON string that you could send to Authorize using whatever platform you use and your own login and secret key.

I should note that even though JSON normally doesn't care which order the values are sent in, Authorize uses a kludgy method to internally convert JSON to XML, so order is in fact, important.

```
{
"createTransactionRequest": {
    "merchantAuthentication": {
        "name": "yourLoginKey",
        "transactionKey": "yourSecretKey"
    },
    "refId": "12345",
    "transactionRequest": {
        "transactionType": "authCaptureTransaction",
        "amount": "3.99",
        "payment": {
            "creditCard": {
                "cardNumber": "4111111111111111",
                "expirationDate": "0522",
                "cardCode": "123"
            }
        },
        "customer": {
            "id": "John Doe"
        },
        "billTo": {
            "firstName": "John",
            "lastName": "Doe",
            "address": "123 My Street",
            "city": "Chicago",
            "state": "IL",
            "zip": "60007",
            "country": "USA"
        }
    }
}
```

}